# Complex condition

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have one issue about select function data from `DataTable` Object in VB.NET.
example:

> in PL/SQL : Select * from Table where A not in (Select B from Table)

so, how I implement this in to `DataTale Object`?

Answer (score 0):

I focus about where condition in that query.

Now I solved my issue by using

```
Dim selectChil = From p In _ps.AsEnumerable()
                 Select p.Field(Of String)(_childKey)
Dim selectParent = (From p In _ps.AsEnumerable()
                   Where selectChil.Contains(p.Field(Of String)(_parentKey)) = False
                   Select p.Field(Of String)(_parentKey))
```

Thanks Guy,